# Attributes not passed to AJAX call for cart items

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am new to AJAX. I have the following Ajax call with a view below:

```
:javascript
$(function(){
    $('.select').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "#{update_cart_path(format: :js)}",
        type: 'post',
        data: { quantity: $("select").val(), id: $("product").attr('id') },
        dataType: 'script',
    })
    });
});


.basket-items

- @products.each do |item|
    .row
        .col-xs-6.col-md-4
            = image_tag item[:image], class: 'img-responsive'
        .col-xs-4.col-md-4
            = item[:name]
        .col-xs-4.col-md-2.select
            = select_tag :quantity, options_for_select((1..10), item[:quantity])
        .col-xs-4.col-md-2
            %span.total-item{'data-widget' => 'summary-total-item'}= to_pounds(item[:total_amount])
        %product{style: "display: none;", :id => item[:id]}
```

AJAX works fine when there is only one product/item in the basket and user tries to change the quantity. But when user adds another/different product into the basket and tries to change the quantity of the added product, the parameters are not passed into the AJAX call for some reason. When debugging, the data parameters passed are from the first product added, not the second one.

What am I doing wrong here? How can you pass the right select parameters from the right product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're re-querying for the `select` element, and always getting the first one when you supply the data.  The jQuery [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method will give you the value of the first item in the selected list.  You can use `this` to supply context to jQuery to get *only* the one you want.

But, by doing that, you'll need to look up to the nearest row, then back down to the `product` tag to find that product id.

Try something like this:

```
:javascript
  $(function(){
    $('.select').change(function(){
      var quantity = $('select', this).val();
      var product_id = $('product', $(this).closest('.row')).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
        url: "#{update_cart_path(format: :js)}",
        type: 'post',
        data: { quantity: quantity, id: product_id },
        dataType: 'script',
      })
    });
  });
```

This can be cleaned up a bit by being more strategic about where you put your change listener, or by using data attributes to put the information in a more convenient place.

Comment: thank you! I am replacing a value (item total) using the following code in update_cart.js.erb  `code` $('[data-widget=summary-total-item]').html( "<%= to_pounds(@item_total) %>" ); `code` (column is also in the main question) but again it replaces all the item lines totals, not a specific selector that was triggered. should I use closest here too?

Comment: I would add the item id to the row, so something like `.row{ id: item[:id] }`.  This way, in your `update_cart.js.erb`, you can have the id of the item to modify, and just change your jQuery to `$('.row#ITEM_ID_HERE [data-widget=summary-total-item]')....` and you'll get the right one.

Answer (score 0):

this looks wrong:  `$("select").val(), id: $("product")`

`$("select")` will match the first select on the page, and `$("product")` will look for a tag like `<product>`, which i don't think exists anywhere.

In the first instance, "quantity" you probably want to say

`$(this).val()`

where `$(this)` is the element that's had the change event put on it, ie the select that's been changed.

For `$("product")`, i think it should be `$("#product")`: the # means "with id equal to".

Also, is the url of the ajax call coming out right?  Maybe it needs to be in `<%= %>` rather than `#{}`.

Also, you have a trailing comma at the end of the options object in your ajax call. (after 'script')